# How to set the JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, event-dispatch-thread

I want to set the `JLabel` to "Downloading..."

Please find the code below

```
if ((JButton) e.getSource() == download) {
            if (!(criteria.trim().equals("---Select Criteria---"))) {
                if (!(detailFileLocation.getText().trim().equals("")
                        || detailFileLocation.getText().trim().equals(null))) {
                    if (!(downloadFileLocation.getText().trim().equals("")
                            || downloadFileLocation.getText().trim().equals(null))) {
                        // Actual content goes here
                        try {
                            status.setText("Downloading...");
                            count = DownloadFileNetDocument.processingDocument(objectStore, criteria,
                                    detailFileLocation.getText(), downloadFileLocation.getText(), env);
                            detailFileLocation.setText("");
                            downloadFileLocation.setText("");
                            selectCriteria.setSelectedIndex(0);
                            if (count > 0) {
                                status.setText(count + " files downloaded successfully");
                                count = 0;
                            } else if (count == 0) {
                                status.setText("No files found");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            status.setText("*** ERROR in downloading files ***");
                        }
                    } else {
                        status.setText("*** Please choose download path for property file ***");
                    }
                } else {
                    status.setText("*** Please select the file containing the values ***");
                }
            } else {
                status.setText("*** Please select a criteria to Download ***");
            }
```

When I click the start download button and then when download completes the label should set to " files downloaded successfully". But when I click on download the label never sets to "Downloading.."

Comment: You should not be using equals function for Null check. Rahter use downloadFileLocation.getText()==null unless you want to check for empty string

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that in mind. :)
But it does not resolve my problem :(

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).  2) **Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.**

Answer (score 0):

Add `status.repaint();` after `status.setText("Downloading...");`